# How to validate angular 2 form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular form validation not working.Validation error message not working properly in angular 2.I did partialy but not working.Can you find where i did mistake?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-keedrl?file=app/app.component.ts

Script:

```
submitform(){

alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.myform.value));

alert(this.myform.value.gender);

if(this.myform.value.placename)
{ 
 this.placename=false;
}
else{
 this.placename=true; 
}
if(this.myform.value.gender)
{
 this.genders=false;
}
else{
 this.genders=true;
}

if(this.myform.value.minAmount)
{
 this.minAmount=false;
}
else{
 this.minAmount=true;
}
if(this.myform.value.maxAmount)
{
 this.maxAmount=false;
} 
else{
 this.maxAmount=true;
}


  if(!this.myform.valid)
  {
  alert("Form Not valid");
  }
  else
  {
  alert("Form valid");   
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your mistake was that you were manually checking form values and trying to validate them yourself, instead of relying on your given form values.

I cleaned up your code, and tried to remove anything unnecessary. I left comments on the things I changed.

Here is the result of my changes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-nprtlb

Here is a detailed version of what I changed:

1. You don't need to use [{ngModel}] when using a form to check for invalid values. You can access the form values anything by doing something like `this.myform.controls['placename'].value`. So I removed all your ngModels, and all your if statements checking to see if they are valid.
2. I added a boolean `formSubmitted` that is set to true when the user tries to submit the form.
3. So that there isn't red text immediately when you open the page, I made the validation (error text) only show after the user tries to submit invalid data. I did this by checking to see if the form value is valid, and that the user has already tried to submit the form. For example, in your html:

`<p *ngIf="formSubmitted && !myform.controls['placename'].valid" class="error">Please select place name</p>`

Comment: I have one doubt..    this will support angular 2  "*ngIf="formSubmitted && !myform.controls['placename'].valid"    ?????????? because i am using only angular 2....I want to support this in angular 2

Comment: Edon.. Thank you so much for your help